# Install Html theme into wordpress via admin panel(Dashboard)

Tags: wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NHrn.png)I have purchased a theme in html. Now I want to upload that in my theme collection of wordpress admin panel. Problem is when I try to do that it says style.css file missing, which is available in assets. I have domain name and I am trying to upload it via admin panel. How to do it. Any idea. My theme is working fine on local server but not installing on admin panel of wordpress in the backend panel of hosted site on godaddy. Or do I need to convert it to wordpress theme first.

Comment: You cant just install an html theme in wordpress and expect it to work. You need to convert it to wordpress ready.

Comment: You mean all the pages?

Comment: Convert the html theme to a Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme files must be in `PHP`, not `HTML`

That's your first issue. There are too many more to list here though. You can't just put in an HTML theme into WordPress.

Comment: I need index.php, style.css, header, footer in php right apart from this I hope I don't need wp_content, wp_include and other folders for it

Comment: I have made a folder with name medi inside that do i need to paste all the files that are mentioned in image uploaded above and then move to its wp_content >>themes>>mytheme (with all php files index, header, footer, blog etc, page).

Comment: You can save the index, style header and footer as a zip file and upload it to the wordpress admin, if you have already installed WordPress on your site through your hosting company or something. You can go to appearance > theme and add the zip file.